# Question about the category of projective $A$-modules of an Artin algebra $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an Artin algebra and $\mathscr{P}(A)$ the category of projective $A$-modules.

I don't know how to show the following facts:

- All objects in $\mathscr{P}(A)$ are injective as objects of $\mathscr{P}(A)$ iff for each simple right $A$-module $S$ we have that $A$ contains a right $A$-submodule isomorphic to $S$.
- mod-$A$ has no module of projective dimension 1 iff all objects of $\mathscr{P}(A)$ are injective as objects of $\mathscr{P}(A)$.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a module $M$ has projective dimension $1$, there is a non-split short exact sequence $0\to P\xrightarrow{i} Q\to M$ with $P$ and $Q$ projective. This, in particular, means there is no map $f:Q\to P$ such that $f\circ i=1_P$, so that $P$ is not injective in $\mathcal P(A)$.

Conversely, if there is a $P$ in $\mathcal P(A)$ which is not injective there, there is an injection $i:R\to S$ and a map $j:R\to P$ such that there is no map $g:S\to P$ such that $g\circ i=j$. This implies that the short exact sequence $0\to R\to S\to S/R\to 0$ is not-split, and therefore the projective dimension of $S/R$ is $1$.

Comment: ♦  Hello, sir. I find this question by chance. Could you tell me why the projective dimension of $S/R=1$ at last?

Comment: Because $Ext^1(S/R,R)\neq0$: the short exact sequence I mention at the end of the answer is a nonzero element.

Comment: ♦ I know that $pd S/R=1$ iff $Ext^2(S/R,-)=0$ and $Ext^1(S/R,- ) \neq0$. And I have not seen $Ext^2(S/R,-)=0$