# How to get the projective dimension just by a non-split sequence?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

In the answer of this question:[Question about the category of projective $A$-modules of an Artin algebra $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265132/question-about-the-category-of-projective-a-modules-of-an-artin-algebra-a/265400#comment4279728_265400)

There is a place I don't know:  Here $A$ is an artin algebra, if there is a projective module $P$ non-injective, then there is a monomorphism $i:R \rightarrow S$ and a map $f: R \rightarrow P$, there is no map $g:S \rightarrow P$ suc that $f=gi$, then the answer of this question gets a non-split short exact sequence of $A$-modules of the form : $0 \rightarrow R \rightarrow S \rightarrow S/R \rightarrow 0$, then since it is not split, $Ext^1 _A(S/R,R) \neq0$. Then how to get the projective dimesion of $S/R=1$? (In my mind, $pd M=1$ iff $Ext^1(M,-) \neq0$ and $Ext^2(M,-)=0$)

Comment: please post all information on R and S from the previous question to make the context clear.

Comment: @Mare I think there are no additional conditions on $R$ and $S$, I have post how to get the non-split short exact sequence.

Comment: The short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow R \rightarrow S \rightarrow S/R \rightarrow 0$ is a projective resolution of $S/R$ of length 1, so its projective dimension is at most 1.

Comment: @HughThomas Why $R$ and $S$ are projective?

Comment: They're projective because they're in the category of projective $A$-modules -- how you would check if $P$ is injective in the category of projective $A$-modules is by starting with a mono in that category.

Comment: @HughThomas Oh, I misunderstand the original meaning. I thought he means $P$ is injective in the category $mod \Lambda$. Get it, thank you.